# How to live a Pleskless life?

Tags: php, web-hosting, cloud

I have always used Linux with Plesk when hosting web projects. It's easy to host multiple websites and setup email accounts but I realized it's overkill sometimes. I think it uses a lot of resources and make customizing the server a hassle.

I'm about to publish a new website and I'm thinking about getting a Media Temple VPS Developer hosting (http://mediatemple.net/webhosting/vps/developer/) or something similar.

I would like some guidance of how to make this leap, how to do stuff without using Plesk. Setup a new website, create emails, a ftp account, databases... I have already played a bit with doing stuff by hand and it seems to me everything is not as integrated as Plesk makes it look like. The thing that confuses me the most is accounts. Apache accounts, email accounts, database accounts, ftp accounts...

I was thinking about using a PaaS provider so I don't have to deal with all of this stuff but I use PHP and I couldn't find a good one that would allow me to customize it with extensions. Also, it seems I can get more performance for cheaper with a VPS/Dedicated server.

So basically, how do you guys do without Plesk and alikes?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the question that you are asking doesn't really fit into the Serverfault category.  I will try to provide you with some basic information that will get you started - But expect this question to be closed as 'off topic'.

Here is a good testing ground for you to play with:
https://www.digitalocean.com/

This will allow you to set up a VPS for ~$5/month.

You can then follow the tutorials, and read document that they have available in the DigitalOcean community section: https://www.digitalocean.com/community

Lastly, I would not suggest managing your own webserver if you have no experience. Hire a professional.

If this is a personal project, have fun.